# DBT macro confusion between data and columns name in pgsql

Tags: postgresql, macros, jinja2, dbt

```
{% macro generate_check_digit_yogesh(input_barcode) %}
{% set barcode_sum = 0 %}
{% set check_digit = 0 %}
{% set current_digit = 0 %}
{% set asx = length(input_barcode) %}

{% if input_barcode|length|int != 13 %}
    {{ length(input_barcode) }}
{% else %}
    {% for i in range(13) %}
        {% set current_digit = input_barcode[i]|int %}
        {% if (i+1) % 2 == 0 %}
            {% set current_digit = current_digit * 1 %}
        {% else %}
            {% set current_digit = current_digit * 3 %}
        {% endif %}
        {% set barcode_sum = barcode_sum + current_digit %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% set check_digit = (10 - (barcode_sum % 10)) % 10 %}
    {% set check_digits = check_digit|string %}
    {{ input_barcode ~ check_digits }}
{% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

so, this is my dbt macro that I want to use and i am calling it like this

```
select
        {{ generate_check_digit_yogesh('ans_key') }} as check_string,
        *
from prepared
```

Here, the ans_key is a column having bp_char data in src table, I waant to check if the length of str is 13, and if it is 13 in length, then I want to add check digit at the end..

Here, {{ length(input_barcode) }} returns the length of string but
{% set current_digit = input_barcode[i]|int %}, this line considers input_barcode as column name i.e. 'ans_key'..

why is that happening.. what am I missing..

I am trying different variationss of code, nothing worked so far..
Also, I tried to create the pgsql function, and use it, but it also fails half way in dbt, but works fine on dbeaver.

Comment: I don't use `dbt` so what follows is semi-educated guessing. Per [Jinja macros](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/jinja-macros), something like: `{% if {{input_barcode}}|length|int != 13 %}
    length({{input_barcode}}) ...` . Basically you need to include `input_barcode` inside `{{ ... }}`. You might also want to look at [Nested curlies](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/dont-nest-your-curlies).